# ESD question related to flash

Tags: voltage, current, memory, flash, esd

I'm using "[SST25VF064C](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005036c.pdf)" for storing the program of the microcomputer.

It was working normally for over a year, but a problem occurred where the data in "SST25VF064C" was corrupted or deleted. When I wrote the program again to the returned "SST25VF064C" using a dedicated writing machine, it started working normally.

Can you please tell me about the factors that cause the data of "SST25VF064C" to be corrupted or deleted during operation. Will it be erased by ESD (Electro Static Discharge) or EOS (Electrical Over Stress)?

Other information:

During operation, WP# (3pin) of "SST25VF064C" is set to Low, and memory write (program/erase) is prohibited. After writing the program with a dedicated writing machine, only read commands are issued from the microcomputer during operation.

Comment: Newbie - Re: "*the data in "SST25VF064C" was corrupted or deleted*" (a) What were the differences between the *correct* contents in the Flash, and the *actual* contents, before it was rewritten? For example, did you see very occasional single bit errors or something else? (b) Have you implemented ECC on the raw data? Or is that not supported when being used to store the firmware of that specific MCU (whatever it is)? (c) Just for context, what is the MCU whose firmware is being held in this flash?

Comment: The most common reason would be damage through excessive writes. This is a pretty bad part with just 10k erase cycles. How often do you write to it?

Answer (score 0):

### Advice:

Next time verify contents by reading memory the actual corruption.

It sounds like an unexpected single-sector/block erase command, from EMC but could be MPU program corruption too.

Do consider some supply power-up transient noise and ESD tests in DVT to measure the margin up to 15kV. The pins can handle 2V over-voltage. What is the coincidence likelihood of EMI and failure?

### How much DVT was done for reliability?

- Next time verify by read-memory the actual corruption and indicate in question
  .
- It sounds like a single-secor/block erase command, from EMC but could be MPU program corruption too.
- Do consider some ESD tests in DVT to measure the margin up to 15kV. The pins can handle 2V over-voltage.
- What is the coincidence likelihood of EMI and failure?
- DVT is normally done for design verification test reliability and margins to design specs.  Although I did some of this as a Newbie in the late 70's . I perfected this process of DVT/PVT during my work in the 80's on many HDD designs.

https://news.ewmfg.com/blog/evt-dvt-pvt-explained

### What program protection designs were in place?

Since you were able to recover with a hard-reset with external firmware write, that tells me you did not have a secure boot code or program memory.

"permanently write-protect the Block-
Protection register bits for each individual block. Each
of the corresponding lock-down bits are one time pro-
grammable (OTP)—once written, they cannot be
erased"  https://www.tme.com/Document/bdbe9ee21c9114ad56b1b16cb973e63b/SST25VF064C.pdf

Although my questions may be rhetorical, they may be something to consider.